# Subtract months to a date using Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, date

I am trying to subtract some months to a date. I have the following DF called df1 where MonthSub is always positive so I have to convert it maybe in negative to subtract the date:

```
+-------------+----------+
|  Date       | MonthSub |
+-------------+----------+
|  31/11/2020 |   12     |
|  25/07/2020 |   5      |
|  11/01/2020 |   1      |
+-------------+----------+
```

And I expect to get the following:

```
+-------------+----------+-------------+
|  Date       | MonthSub | Result      |
+-------------+----------+-------------+
|  31/11/2020 |   12     |  31/11/2019 | 
|  25/07/2020 |   5      |  25/02/2020 |
|  11/01/2020 |   1      |  11/12/2019 |
+-------------+----------+-------------+
```

Schema of DF1:

```
root
 |-- Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MonthSub: string (nullable = true)
```

What I am doing:

```
df1 = df1.withColumn("MonthSub", col("MonthSub").cast(IntegerType))

val dfMonth = df1.withColumn("Result", add_months(to_date(col("Date"), "dd-MM-yyyy"), col("MonthSub")))
```

But I constantly getting null values.
Are there other options to do this? or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the schema of your dataframe in the post ? (printSchema() function)

Comment: @David done, I tried to convert MonthSub to int and Date to date but doesn't work, updated the code with the cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `add_months` with negative months value as below

```
val dfMonth = df1.withColumn("Result", add_months(
  to_date(col("Date"), "dd/MM/yyyy"), col("MonthSub") * lit(-1))
)


dfMonth.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----------+--------+----------+
|Date      |MonthSub|Result    |
+----------+--------+----------+
|30/11/2020|12      |2019-11-30|
|25/07/2020|5       |2020-02-25|
|11/01/2020|1       |2019-12-11|
+----------+--------+----------+
```

You can change the date format as you like.